# Interpolate function using Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, interpolation, apache-commons-math

I'm trying to implement some Interpolation functions to plot some values where the X value = Date.seconds and the Y value = double.

I'v been researching using the `Apache Commons Math`  lib to achieve this and I've found a method I think I might be able to use [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.LinearInterpolator)

The method I'm trying to understand:

```
public double linearInterp(double[] x, double[] y, double xi) {
   // return linear interpolation of (x,y) on xi
   LinearInterpolator li = new LinearInterpolator();
   PolynomialSplineFunction psf = li.interpolate(x, y);
   double yi = psf.value(xi);
   return yi;
}
```

I don't understand where I'm supposed to get the `xi` value from?

What is xi what value do I pass into this method for xi, am I supposed to loop through my array of `X` values and pass in the ith element of `X` with the array of `X` and `Y`?

And when I want to plot this new data do I use the returned `yi` along with the passed in `xi` to plot?

Comment: Do you want to plot the interpolation function itself, i.e. create images like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Interpolation_example_linear.svg or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Interpolation_example_polynomial.svg using a set of X/Y points? Or do you want to get the Y value(s) for X value(s) that aren't in your original dataset and plot those?

Comment: I want to plot the interpolation function itself, I'm using `highchart.js` to plot the data. My ultimate goal is to have an extrapolation function to plot points in the future using the using my set of X/Y points. maybe using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076041/extrapolation-in-java
But I've been led to believe if I have an interpolation function, I can use that function to extrapolate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `interpolate` method expects arrays of pairs (here called `x` and `y`) and returns a function (`psf`) that fits these values as best as possible.

This function is then used to interpolate the yi-value of a given xi-value (which is normally not contained in the x/y array used to define the function).

So you have pairs containing of x- and y-values defining a function and use this function to interpolate missing values.

See the [userguide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html) on Apache Commons (Chapter 4.4: Interpolation).

---

Example:

[image: badly drawn example of a spline interpolation]

The green dots are known value pairs. These are defined by the `x` and `y` value arrays.

When calling `interpolate`, the returned `PolynomialSplineFunction` returns the function that is approximated using the known value pairs. The shape of the funtion is defined by the type of [`UnivariateInterpolator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/UnivariateInterpolator.html) that is used. In the question example, a `LinearInterpolator` is used. The drawing shows the function returned by a spline interpolator.

The red dot symbolizes a value with an unknown y-value on the interpolated function (this would be the value with an x-value of `xi` in the question example).

If you need to calculate more than one extra value, use a function like this

```
public double[] linearInterp(double[] x, double[] y, double[] xi) {
   LinearInterpolator li = new LinearInterpolator(); // or other interpolator
   PolynomialSplineFunction psf = li.interpolate(x, y);

   double[] yi = new double[xi.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < xi.length; i++) {
       yi[i] = psf.value(xi[i]);
   }
   return yi;
}
```

---

A calculation example:

```
public class Interpolate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] x = { 0, 50, 100 };
        double[] y = { 0, 50, 200 };

        LinearInterpolator interp = new LinearInterpolator();
        PolynomialSplineFunction f = interp.interpolate(x, y);

        System.out.println("Piecewise functions:");
        Arrays.stream(f.getPolynomials()).forEach(System.out::println);

        double value = f.value(70);
        System.out.println("y for xi = 70: " + value);
    }
}
```

Three known value pairs are given:

> (0, 0)
>   (50, 50)
>   (100, 200)

One value is unknown:

> (70, ?)

The `LinearInterpolator` interpolates the given values and generates a function with two piecewise, linear polynomials:

```
y = x             (for x values < 50)
y = 50 + 3 * x    (for x-values >= 50)
```

The value of the interpolated `xi` (here: 70) is

```
y = 50 + 3 * (70 - 50) = 110
```

Comment: I have a much better understanding after reading that, thank you. How would I choosing an `xi` value to use, assuming I want to use a value not found in the set, is there a method of choosing an appropriate `xi`, do I use the same `xi` to interpolate the entire data set? I'm guessing yes and then change `xi` and run through the sets again for a different result?

Comment: @Johntk _do I use the same xi to interpolate the entire data set?_ - It's actually the other way round: you use the dataset to interpolate `xi`. I'll add a little example.

Comment: @Johntk I added more explanation, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this answer, I understand how it works now, in my example the `xi` is a `date` and passing a new `date` in would be my `xi` or passing in several dates would be my `xi[i]`, I would then use the data set to interpolate `xi[i]`
I ran into a `OutOfRangeException` when I tried to extrapolate with the method you provided, but the extrapolation method I linked to in the initial question works, but I'm having trouble getting good results back due to using `dates` rather than coordinates, I'll need to post a new question I think. thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry i should have said the `OutOfRangeException ` was due to me passing in values outside the data set range, nothing wrong with the function you provided me with.