# How to interpolate/resample unequally spaced timeseries data in java?

Tags: java, time-series, signal-processing, resampling, linear-interpolation

I have a lot of movement data from a sensor of an android phone. The sensor-data is not equally spaced. The first column is the timestamp, the second to fourth are the values.

```
1476998233373060.00 -13.724.029 -0.32222483 0.6645355
1476998243378590.00 -18.152.794 -0.24412125 0.8499975
1476998253388590.00 -2.187.418  -0.30240154 12.714.252
1476998263396320.00 -22.723.544 -0.34668386 20.311.832
1476998273406320.00 -2.164.714  -0.37845135 24.795.723
1476998283410820.00 -21.867.716 -0.54110456 25.763.245
1476998293416360.00 -2.237.784  -0.6974954  22.364.025
1476998303426360.00 -24.321.814 -0.8333628  19.332.075
1476998313436360.00 -2.759.505  -0.7860836  18.638.668
1476998323446360.00 -26.884.165 -0.6191631  19.814.253
1476998333456360.00 -22.407.222 -0.49433255 21.869.373
1476998343410860.00 -14.944.388 -0.36760736 25.031.233
1476998353420860.00 -0.94890594 -0.42283204 28.025.484
1476998363430860.00 -0.8609359  -0.38489643 29.441.748
1476998373440860.00 -0.85431504 -0.35977864 29.717.588
1476998383450860.00 -10.072.823 -0.47319135 29.098.034
1476998393460860.00 -12.651.224 -0.51026744 30.539.284
1476998403470860.00 -19.531.182 -0.8022793  33.434.896
1476998413480860.00 -29.464.073 -11.810.504 32.431.068
1476998423471860.00 -36.945.052 -13.393.123 29.437.609
```

What do I have to do, to get equally spaced timestamps and according sensor-values.
Matlab or python aren't an option.

EDIT:
So if ever someone finds this in the future and needs the answer... I used [this method to interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523685/520897). The step-width I used to interpolate is the one difference in these timestamps, which came up the most.

Comment: what do you mean by equally spaced? that there should always be exactly one space between the values or what?

Comment: The difference between the timestamps varies.

Comment: Could you comment on why you believe you need that? The terminology you’re looking for is ‘equidistant timeseries’ btw

Comment: I want to FFT it.

Comment: And how are you going to calculate the FFT if Matlab or python is not an option? Will you use some library or will you implement the FFT in Java yourself?

Comment: Rosettacode helped there.