# interpolation out of range apache

Tags: scala, apache-spark, interpolation, apache-commons

I would like to get interpolation outside of a known range. For instance, I need to get an interpolated value for a point with index 0. Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.SplineInterpolator
val a = Array(0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
val b  = a.zipWithIndex.map(i => (i._2.toDouble + 1.0, i._1))
val interp = new SplineInterpolator()
val filler = interp.interpolate(b.map(_._1), b.map(_._2))
println(filler.value(0.0))
```

However, I get the following exception (Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.OutOfRangeException: 0 out of [1, 4] range...). Is there a way to get an interpolated value?

Comment: So you're looking for _extrapolation_? If so - here's a Java answer for that same question that can easily be translated to Scala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076041/extrapolation-in-java

Comment: thanks Tzach Zohar